# Informatica power center parameters with multiple values

Tags: parameters, mapping, informatica

I have this filter in SQL:

```
WHERE DEP_NAME IN ( 'SALES','ACCOUNTING')
```

How can I pass these two values in a mapping parameter in order to use in in the mapping either in SQ or FILER TRANSFORMATION.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass all values in IN clause using a parameter.

1. define a parameter like this `$$FILTER_CLAUSE= 'SALES','ACCOUNTING'`
2. use it in your SQL - `WHERE DEP_NAME IN ( $$FILTER_CLAUSE )`

This will work in SQ and FIL. You can pass as many values as you want.